# Good reference site for SQL/RDBMS

Tags: sql, reference

One of the aspects of computer science/practical software engineering I am weaker at is actually doing significant work in database systems. That is to say, I can do simple queries on smaller datasets, no problem. However, working with complex queries on large datasets invokes a level of understanding of databases beyond me right now. For example, I built an amusing query some time ago that computed a join using a n^2 size where n=20,000- the hosting server suspended my account for blowing the CPU. Shocking.

I am interested in bringing myself up to speed on how to design schema and queries that, well, don't bring down the server. Pursuant to that end, what materials do you recommend that discuss professional database/SQL design and writing?

Answer (score 1):

I would go to the bookstore and pick out some books on performance tuning for the database of your choice (it is very differnet depending onteh database backend). This will help you understand what not to do which is critical to designing databases.

Here's a site with a lot of good info
http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Category:Data_Management

Comment: I'l respectfully disagree.  I think there's a fair amount of non-product specific knowledge to be had before delving into the implementation details for any particular RDBMS.

Comment: Your link doesn't have any info, HLGEM.

Comment: Yes it does, you just have to investigate the links on it.

Answer (score 1):

For generic SQL I would go for [Celko's books](http://celko.com/books.htm). For vendor specific, it depends on the platform of your choice. I know the SQL Server platform well and for that my praise go to the [Inside series](http://www.insidesqlserver.com/thebooks.html).

Blogs are also usefull, look at the [all time SQL tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=sql&sort=stats&pagesize=30) right here on SO and check the top answerers info, some have personal blogs that are very usefull. Eg. go through [Quassnoi's blog](http://explainextended.com/), it has a LOT of useful info on MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server.